# Spock. How to mock java.lang.Class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a class with field of type java.lang.Class:

```
Class clazz
```

That is then used in sevaral methods in the following manner:

```
Object profile = objectDAO.get(clazz, id)
...
clazz.newInstance()
```

The problem is that I encounter problems with mocking the java.lang.Class. I tried:

```
Mock(Class)
```

and got:

> org.spockframework.mock.CannotCreateMockException: Cannot create mock
>   for class java.lang.Class because Java mocks cannot mock final
>   classes. If the code under test is written in Groovy, use a Groovy
>   mock.

but:

```
GroovyMock(Class)
```

gives:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: java.lang.Class

Is there any proper way to mock Class to verify it's interactions?

Comment: Why you dont use own class or interface?  You can generic type in your DAO-layer.

Comment: Anton, it's rather undoable. Could you please share your design so we can provide an alternative solution?

Comment: @Opal, thanks for suggestion. I've solved the problem by passing everywhere I needed an `Object.class` and it's dummy instance verifying results but not the interactions themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should not be doing this as I suspect that it can have some side effects, but to answer the question the following will work:

```
def dummyObject = new Object()

Class.metaClass.static.newInstance = { dummyObject }

def clazz = String
assert clazz.newInstance() == dummyObject

clazz = Integer
assert clazz.newInstance() == dummyObject
```

Also note that `Class.newInstance` should be set to the original at the end

Answer (score 0):

How about making a wrapper class around Class? You can then let the wrapper class implement an interface and then create a mock for that interface:

```
public interface ClassWrapper {
    Class<?> getClazz();
    Object newInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException;
}

public class ClassWrapperImpl implements ClassWrapper {
    private Class<?> clazz;

    public ClassWrapperImpl(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Class getClazz() {
        return this.clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Object newInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return this.clazz.newInstance();
    }

    // add more methods of the Class class that needs to be wrapped
}

public class SomeClass {
    private ClassWrapper cw;

    void methodA(Class<?> clazz) {
        cw = new ClassWrapperImpl(clazz); // (or better use dependency injection)
    }

    void methodB() {        
        Object profile = objectDAO.get(cw.getClazz(), id);          
        cw.newInstance();           
    }
}
```